# Can I trade pokemon between different versions(e.g. Pokemon Ruby and Emerald)?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-third-generation

I have a copy of the US Pokemon Emerald game and a copy of ESP Pokemon Ruby game version.

Can I trade between the two versions?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trade, but you will need a link cable. Ruby and Sapphire aren't compatible with the wireless connectors.

Comment: But where should I go to trade in the game? I mean, where in the poké should I go in both games?

Comment: You need to have the Pokedex and at least 2 Pokemon in your party to able trade. Go to the second floor of the Pokemon Center and talk to the lady in the middle.

Comment: Emerald and ruby aren't equal. The person in ruby in the center of the second floor of the pokemon center isn't the same in emerald.

Comment: @Garmen1778 You are right, the Link Club lady is on the right in Emerald